# SQL Server - How to get 2 values before and after timestamp from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, date-arithmetic

I was just wondering if anyone can help me with this problem.

I have two tables - Table 1 & Table 2.

What I'm trying to do is to find 2 timestamps before and after 'date' from Table 1, so everything highlighted in pink in Table 2.

How can I do this in Microsoft SQL Server? ideally without using CTE. Unfortunately, CTE is not supported by Tableau.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I would take a peek at row_number() both ASC and DESC.   I would also post sample data as text so contributors don't have to do data entry

Comment:  Please don't expect us to work with [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, it cannot be consumed, used or searched on; please use *text* for text. What have you tried so far? where are you stuck? What sort of date is `11/1/22`? Is that January or November? 1922?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using a CROSS JOIN, datediff() and row_number()

```
Select Date
      ,Value
      ,ID
 From  (
        Select A.Date
              ,A.Value
              ,B.ID
              ,RN1 = row_number() over (order by datediff(second,a.date,b.date) desc) 
              ,RN2 = row_number() over (order by datediff(second,a.date,b.date) asc) 
         From Table2  A
         Cross Join Table1 B  
       ) A
 Where RN1 in (2,3)
   or  RN2 in (2,3)
 Order By Date
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select this specific range of rows in `table2`, the simplest approach might be `union all`:

```
(
    select top (3) t2.date, t2.value
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2 on t2.date < t1.date
    order by t2.date desc 
)
union all
(
    select top (3) t2.date, t2.value
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2 on t2.date > t1.date
    order by t2.date
)
```

Both suqueries start from the reference date in `table1`, and then fetch the previous (resp. next) 3 records in `table2`, using `order by` and `fetch`. The combination of the two datasets gives you the result you want.

With a very small `table1` and with the relevant index in place on `table2(date)`, both subqueries should execute very efficiently. Adding column `value` to the `table2` index might further help performance, by making the index *covering* for the query.